# TortoiseSVN/TortoisePlink prompts for "login as" on any working copy operation

Tags: windows-7, svn, putty, tortoise-svn

My work desktop PC has just been refreshed and now I'm using Windows 7 64bit.

Seeing as my employer uses Ubuntu development servers with svn 1.5, I've installed [PuTTY, Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and [TortoiseSVN 1.5.10-x64](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). I've set up pageant to use my ssh key and it and PuTTY seem to be working fine.

However, if I try to do any operation on the working copy, I get a TortoisePlink dialog, asking me "login as:".

It will work if I enter my ssh username for the server the svn repository is located on, but often it will require me to enter the username multiple times (I just tested "show log" and I had to enter my username 4 times). However, it doesn't ask me for my password, so it must be getting my ssh key from pageant.

When I used Windows XP, after setting up pageant correctly, TortoiseSVN never prompted me for anything.

Why is it asking for a username when it didn't before? Isn't that information stored in the working copy? And how can I specify the username I want it to use for a particular working copy so that I wont have to enter it again?

**Note**
Because our servers have svn1.5 and svn automatically upgrades working copies to the current format and working copy formats are not backwards-compatible, I need to use TortoiseSVN 1.5 for a hassle-free life.
So any solution which doesn't involve upgrading my svn or tortoisesvn is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This is a known issue](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2011-12/0147.shtml).  Tortoise 64 bit is pointing their finger at PuTTy 32 bit :

Comment: Thanks for that. I'd give you an upvote, but apparently, I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: It does not help if you are using `svn+ssh://` protocol with the user in the working copy url and inner externals like `//svn.code.sf.net/p/blabla`. It still asks for the login (not password) for each external. Even more, it could stuck on asking logins if you recently switched externals from `svn://...` to `//...` (without the scheme part). You have to recheckout working copy to fix infinite loop of asking.

Answer (score 7):

By default, PuTTY will always ask you for username, unless it is already provided in the hostname or in the session settings.

- a) Modify the hostname (in your SVN address) to read `user@host` instead of just `host`.
- b) Open PuTTY, go to *Configuration → Connection → Data*, enter your name as "Auto-login username" (**or** pick the "Use system username" option). Go back to *Session*, select "Default session" from list, click *Save*.

The same applies to all programs in PuTTY package (PuTTY itself, *plink*, *pscp*, *psftp*).